# is there a way to use simple_form in show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I've spent considerable amount of time making a form in simple_form.  It had 96 fields! I've split the form in different steps.  Each step is made as a partial.

Now I have to prepare the form for `show.html.erb` .  I thought rendering the same partials would just show the form to the user but ofcourse If I try to do that it gives me an error like:

```
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0xb6d8712c>:0xb6d85f20>
```

Most of my partials have code like below:

```
<%= f.input :name, :label=>"Preferred Name",:label_html => {:class => "form_label"}%>
```

I am just trying to leverage the work I've done instead of coding all fields again for `show.html.erb`

Are there any tricks I can use here?

Comment: How did you solve this? Technically show.html.erb doesn't need a form or input fields, so simple_FORM wouldn't apply. However often you want a view that shows data as labels, then the labels "morph" into input fields when you click on Edit. It would be nice if simple_form offered a way to render the same partial in "show" and "edit" modes.

Comment: @MarkBerry - take a look this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64673778/1018996

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be sending `show.html.erb`'s `form_for` builder variable when rendering the partial:

```
#show.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @something do |builder| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'somepartial', :locals => { :f => builder } %>
  ...
<% end %>

#_somepartial.html.erb
<%= f.input :name, :label=>"Preferred Name",:label_html => {:class => "form_label"} %>
```

Comment: great! that works. however, data shows inside textfields. this will work for my edit.html.erb.  Any way to show it as data and not textfields using the same partial?

Comment: Pass in `{ ... , locals => :some_variable => @something}` and do `<%= some_variable.name %>`. Alternatively, `<%= f.object[:name] %>` in the partial *might* work (I have not tried it). But I personally prefer passing in the variable explicitly.

Comment: I didn't understand. you mean change `_somepartial.html.erb` to have `<%= some_variable.name%>` instead of simple_form code of `...<%= f.input :name, :label=>"Preferred Name"...` but that will involve me changing the whole partial.

Comment: What do you mean by "show it as data and not textfields"? In the edit partial, if you want to render a input field you use `f.input`, and if you want to render a non-input field, use `somevariable.xx`. You would need to change the partial for this. If you want to avoid doing that for whatever reason, I suppose using jQuery to prevent editing the input field and then using CSS to make it look like it's not a input field would be possible to do. Why not just do it the right way the first time?

Comment: ok. I was seeing if same piece of code in the partial would render an input field when `new` action is requested and render a non-input field when `show` action is requested.  But it seems like i'll need to have different partials for both. right?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

This might be a hacky solution - but in a jam it works really well.

This is my `_form` partial...

```rb
<%
disabled ||= false
%>
<%= simple_form_for incident_report do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name,  disabled: disabled %>
  <%= f.input :last_name,   disabled: disabled %>
  <%= f.input :email,       disabled: disabled %>
  <%= f.input :phone,       disabled: disabled %>
  <% unless disabled %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% else %>
    Put show page content here!
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I pass in a **disabled** var to simply re-used the form code and hide the submit button.

My Show Page:

```rb
<%= render 'form', incident_report: @incident_report, disabled: true %>
```

New Page (same as normal..)

```html
<h1>New Report</h1>
<%= render 'form', incident_report: @incident_report %>
```

Toggle between the edit and show page gives you beautifully consistent UI.

Any feedback is much appreciated!